# GitHub diff incorrect with previously-merged commits still showing up

Tags: github

Okay I'm working on a shared repo with 2 other people. This started happening recently, we thought we fixed it, and today it happened again.

We have

- development branch (devs pull from this, make new branches, push those to GH, submit PR to merge into development after approval, this seems to work just fine)
- staging branch (this only merges from development, no one works with it directly except to create PRs to push changes up to the preproduction layer)
- production branch (only merges from staging, deploys to production environment)

The problem is that merging from development to staging started to acquire a growing list of commits that wouldn't go away, and the diffs would keep showing up. We reset the branches and started clean today. Today, I pulled dev, made a new branch, edited 3-4 lines of code in one file, add/commit/pushed my new branch, submitted a PR to merge into dev, it was approved, we merged, great. We then merged that small change to staging.

Hours later, I have another small change, 4-5 lines of code, to a different file. I pull dev, make a new branch, edit, add, commit, push, submit PR, merge into dev... the diff looks right, it's approved, we merged, dev is in a good spot.

Now: when we do the PR to merge from development into staging, it lists both commits from the day, and lists both files as diff. This is what led to our problem before, the old commits are still there and the diff thinks the files have changed (one has changed, one is already there from the previous merge).

But if you manually click into the code on GH, you can see that the code from the earlier merge is already in staging. And if I pull all branches to my local environment and run git diff between staging and development there are no diffs. But the PRs show diffs as if the old file is still on staging.

I just tried creating a PR through CLI and got the same issue. I'm totally flummoxed. Would love to know if this rings a bell for anyone.

FOLLOW-UP: If I change the compare URL from 3 dots to 2 dots, I get the correct result. I'm trying to wrap my head around what this means. I feel like a complete noob so please treat me like one.

FOLLOW-UP TO THE FOLLOW-UP: This is what Chat-GPT tells me the 3 dots is: "A 3-dot diff is like saying "If I were to merge B into A right now, what changes would be applied to A?"" But this isn't true (of my repo). The changes in A are already in B. They are there on the GH website, in the branch when you pull as well and just to reiterate running 'git diff' locally shows 0 differences. Also my head hurts and now I'm going to take a nap.